# Inner Join with CASE statement is not working in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two `tables` have Account-Codes As Below,

```
table 1:

account  

50000
50006
50015
50105
50150
50155
50165

table 2:

Account

50000
50010
50140
50105
50150
50155
50165
```

I need to Join these two `tables`. If any account codes of `table-1` is not matching with `table-2`, then I have implicitly change table-1 account-code to table-2 account code.

I have done something as below,

```
 SELECT T1.Account, T2.Account
 FROM table1 t1 
 INNER JOIN table2 t2
 on (t2.account =  CASE t1 .account 
                   WHEN 50015 THEN 50010
                   WHEN 50006 THEN 50140
                   ELSE  t1 .account 
                    END )
```

But I got only matched codes as output,

```
account Account
50000   50000
50105   50105
50150   50150
50155   50155
50165   50165
```

I didn't get the Unmatched Account codes i.e `(50006 and 50015)`. Could anyone help me to find out what's wrong here?

my expected output is

```
account Account
50000   50000
50006   50140
50015   50010
50105   50105
50150   50150
50155   50155
50165   50165
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Should it go by Index? First from the table1 should check with first from table2 etc.?

Comment: Your question is confusing. Matching account is clear, but how can you find unmatched account? any account number which does not exists in the other table is an mismatch record. is there any other field in those tables? what is the mapping between accounts?

Comment: I tried your code and its working see [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2d5bc/1/0)

Comment: @FLICKER, If any un-matched account found i have to convert that into matched account

Comment: What does "If any un-matched account found i have to convert that into matched account" mean? It would be clearer if you would include your expected result. That statement does not make any sense. If it doesn't match, it doesn't match. We can only assume that magic determines what the number should be when it doesn't match.

Comment: ok let me make this clear. for e.g: table-1 have an account code 50006 and table-2 have 50140. both are not matching. I this case I need to change 50006 as 50140 while joining the tables. hope it is clear

Comment: @bmsqldev i have very much confusion in table1 we have 50006 corresponding to table2 50010, same as 50015 and 50140. so why we need set of 50006-50140, 50015-50010 instead of 50006-50010, 50015-50140 ?

Comment: well that's a part of our requirement. I need to update amount corresponding to the 50006 account code in 50140 and so on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `CASE` then `DISTINCT` the data, that will give you generic solution

```
-- table1
declare  @table1 table
(account  bigint)

insert into @table1 values (50000)
insert into @table1 values (50006)
insert into @table1 values (50015)
insert into @table1 values (50105)
insert into @table1 values (50150)
insert into @table1 values (50155)
insert into @table1 values (50165)

-- table2
declare  @table2 table
(account  bigint)

insert into @table2 values (50000)
insert into @table2 values (50010)
insert into @table2 values (50140)
insert into @table2 values (50105)
insert into @table2 values (50150)
insert into @table2 values (50155)
insert into @table2 values (50165)


-- QUERY
select distinct t1.account as Account1, 
Account2 = case 
    when  t1.account = t2.account then t2.account else  t1.account
    end
from @table1 t1, @table2 t2
```

RESULT

```
Account1    Account2
50000       50000
50006       50006
50015       50015
50105       50105
50150       50150
50155       50155
50165       50165
```

**EDIT** after comment - *well that's a part of our requirement. I need to update amount corresponding to the 50006 account code in 50140 and so on...*

```
select distinct t1.account as Account1, 
Account2 = case 
    when  t1.account = 50006 then 50140
    when  t1.account = 50015 then 50010 
    else  t1.account end
from @table1 t1 , @table2 t2
```

RESULT

```
Account1    Account2
50000       50000
50006       50140
50015       50010
50105       50105
50150       50150
50155       50155
50165       50165
```

Answer (score 2):

Try  this

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c7671/5)

```
SELECT T1.Account, T2.Account
 FROM table1 t1 
 INNER JOIN table2 t2
 on (t1.account =  CASE t1 .account 
                   WHEN 50015 THEN t2 .account+5
                   WHEN 50006 THEN t2 .account-134
                   ELSE  t2 .account 
                    END )
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
   SELECT T1.Account, T2.Account
   FROM table1 t1 
   INNER JOIN table2 t2
   on (t2.account =  CASE 
               WHEN t1.account = 50015 THEN 50010
               WHEN t1.account=50006 THEN 50140
               ELSE  t1.account 
                END )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT T1.Account, T2.Account,(CASE t1 .account 
                   WHEN 50015 THEN 50010
                   WHEN 50006 THEN 50140
                   ELSE  t1 .account 
                    END) as New_Account
 FROM table1 t1 
INNER JOIN table2 t2
 on (t2.account =  t1.account )
```